# How to match everything BUT last two parts of URL domain

Tags: regex, parsing

I have some urls, `red.testurl.com` and `new.red.testurl.com` and I would like to match and remove everything but `testurl.com`.

I have tried with `^.*?(?=\.+[com]+$)` which removes everything but the com, but I also want to include the word before com as well.

Similarly, I tried with `^(\w*)*(?!\w*\.com)` but if there's more than one word in front of `testurl`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out by combining the two!

`^.*?(?=\w*\.\w+$)`

Even if it ends with similar to`.io` it works! Similar to `.co.uk` I'll deal with separately though

Comment: You could use an alternation for the `.co.uk` part `^.*?(?=\w+\.(?:co\.uk|\w+)$)`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tASdXq/1) or use a capturing group [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MyHZE1/1)